# Not able to connect to internet on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, networking, windows, windows-7, internet

I have a dual boot on my PC.
I can access Internet through Windows but cannot do it through Ubuntu.

I was able to connect to Internet on both OSses till some days ago, when my brother reset my router(or modem,I don't know) to factory settings and internet stopped working on both OSses. After some tweaking the setting in the DSL setting page in windows(192.168.1.1), It started working properly without having to connect manually through the network dialog.

But it still isn't working on Ubuntu 12.04 . And additionally, I can't open the settings page from Ubuntu but in Windows it opens up perfectly.

In ubuntu I tried doing `sudo pppoeconf` but it said that it cannot detect access concentrator on `eth0`.

Please help me connect to the Internet in Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I just followed these [instructions](http://azizsaboor.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/removing-pppoeconf-settings-in-ubuntu-9-10/) and got rid of `pppoeconf` settings, and made Ubuntu use DHCP instead of trying to connect.

```
sudo rm /etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider
```

Then edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to remove the section that defines dsl-provider, and change

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

to

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

that sounds as if ur ubuntu config isnt hooked up by the router at all. u could verify that by trying to **ping ur router**.

If u "tweaked the settings" of the router, what exactly did u do ?
i assume u may have set the **DHCP** server to manual which would mean that u have simply to give ur ubuntu machine a **static ip**  **OR** u just **enable DHCP** SERVER in ur routers config again.